# How do i create i Windows TreeView with multiple selection (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, treeview

I am trying to implement a custom draw tree view in my WinAPI application. I found [samples to manage the custom draw](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/248496) etc. However i do not find a solution to enable multiple selections. I found a attribute TVS_EX_MULTISELECT, but this [seems not to be supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), although there is a [article about using that flag in c#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21051/TreeView-Multiselect-Using-TVS-EX-MULTISELECT-in-C) and there is even a [article from MSDN Magazine explaining](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163384.aspx) this flag. But setting

```
TreeView_SetExtendedStyle(hWndTreeView, TVS_EX_MULTISELECT, TVS_EX_MULTISELECT);
```

seems to have no effect.

Finally i found a [code project implementing a custom draw tree control with multiple selections](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30484/MultiSelection-TreeControl), but this seems quite complicated and its based on MFC.

How can i create a plain tree view (using custom draw) and enable multiple selections on it? WPF/MFC etc or even Qt are not an option. We use a large custom build C++ Framework based on WinAPI.

Comment: Tree is a container that leads to complicated questions regarding selection of nodes. I think that better way to represent some selection in a tree is to use check boxes on nodes. Such implementation allows even usages like check or un-check all children, also there is nice representation if children is selected, but collapsed. And so on...

Comment: A Fair concern - but even in Visual Studio (210 and 2013) its possible to select i.e. multiple source files in the Solution explorer tree.

Comment: Yes it looks nice, I agree, but there are questions like, 1. what happens if you collapse a parent with selected children nodes, not just to children but to whole selection, also 2. what happens to selected nodes if an arrow key is pressed, should a new node be selected after key release and which one, and so on